# Split data in one column and convert them into column headers in ORACLE

Tags: oracle11g

I'm having a table like this. All I need to do is split the data in specified column into new column headers and assign matching values to those columns which are in another column.

```
App_No       Code     Amount

  a           rvd      100
  a           pqd      200
  b           srv      100
  b           rvd      500
  b           crb      300
  c           srv      200

and I need to select this data and convert them to a format like this.

    App_No      rvd     pqd     srv     crb

      a         100     200      0       0
      b         500      0      100     300  
      c          0       0      200      0
```

I need to make column headers with code data. how can I achieve this in oracle? can I do this with 'pivot'?

Comment: Is the set of possible values of `Code` column known in advance?

Comment: yes. there are only 16 values and those are known values.

Answer (score 1):

### TRY THIS:

```
select  
app_no,
nvl(rvd,0)rvd,
nvl(rqd,0)rqd,
nvl(srv,0)srv,
nvl(crb,0)crb
from
main_table 
PIVOT
(
sum(amount) for (code) in (
'rvd' as rvd,
'rqd' as rqd,
'srv' as srv,
'crb' as crb
) 
)
```

Comment: Thaks Ersin. It works fine. but there is one problem. There are empty cells. how  can I put 0s to empty cells.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to put 0 s to empty cells in this result set?

Comment: what you mean empty cells ? you can use nvl func for null values

Comment: Every App_no doesn't have rvd,rqd... all values. some have only 2 or 3 from those. so empty means null values. but here the result set for the null values shows nothing. just an empty cell for null value.

Comment: you can use nvl ?

Comment: can you share your example data

Comment: Not clear what you asked? what do u mean example data?

Comment: yep example data and your select query